# Array of complex numbers

Tags: c++, array

> A class `Array` which contains two data members: a pointer on array of complex numbers and the length of the array. Implement a function for reading the array. The class should have a constructor, destructor and copy constructor. In the main program, enter the array of complex numbers.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"

using namespace std;

class Array{
private:
complex *n;
int length;
public:
Array(void);
Array(int,complex *);
~Array();
Array(const Array &);
void print_array(void);
};

Array::Array(void){
}

Array::Array(int _length, complex *_n){
length=_length;
n=new complex[length];
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
n[i]=_n[i];
}
}

Array::~Array(){
delete [] n;
n=0;
}

 Array::Array(const Array & _n){
 length=_n.length;
 n=new complex[length];
 for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
 n[i]=_n.n[i];
 }
 }

 void Array::print_array(void){
 for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
 cout<<""<<(n[i]).return_real()<<"+("<<(n[i]).return_imaginary()<<")j"    <<endl;
 }
 }

 int main()
 {
 complex *numbers;
 int length;
 float a,b;
 cout<<"How many complex numbers you will enter? "<<endl;
 cin>>length;
 numbers=new complex[length];
 cout<<"Enter real and imaginary parts of "<<length<<" complex numbers"   <<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
 cin>>a>>b;
 numbers[i]=complex(a,b);
 }
 Array n1(length, numbers);
 n1.print_array();
 Array n2(n1);
 }
```

**complex.cpp**

```
#include "complex.h"

complex::complex(void){
}

complex::complex(float a,float b){
real=a;
imaginary=b;
}

complex::~complex(){
}

float complex::return_real(void){
return real;
}

float complex::return_imaginary(void){
return imaginary;
}
```

**complex.h**

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED
#define COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED

class complex{
private:
float real;
float imaginary;
public:
complex(void);
complex(float,float);
~complex();
float return_real(void);
float return_imaginary(void);
};

#endif // COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED
```

I tested it and it works. I want to know if there is something I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't well indented, but maybe that's only your post on codereview (if it isn't, please consider indenting your code, that helps!)

There's a flaw in your code: you thought about reimplementing `Array`'s [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) (which is good), but you didn't think about the [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) (which is implicitly defined).
Currently, this code is legal, and is very likely to cause undefined behaviour (that may or may not "work", you don't know, usually you'll get a segfault when it doesn't):

```
#include "array.hpp" // let's say you moved the array definition there

void uselessAssignment(const Array& a) {
  Array b;
  b = a; // call to the implicitly defined assignment operator!
  // call to b destructor (you just deleted the memory allocated by a)
}

int main(int, char*[]) {
  complex complexNumbers[42];
  Array a(42, complexNumbers);
  uselessAssignment(a);
  a.printArray();
  return 0;
}
```

To correct that, either redefine the [implicit assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) or mark it as `delete`.

Otherwise that seems like a fine minimal implementation, it could be improved though:
- you forgot a delete in the main, that's not extremely important because the OS will free the memory anyway when the program terminates, but that's not really clean
- i've learnt today that [you should avoid prefixing your names with an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) (stack overflow link)
- in complex.cpp you can use the [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize the real and imaginary parts (your code works fine, i just personally find it cleaner):

```
complex::complex(float a, float b) : 
real(a), 
imaginary(b) {}
```

- you may want your complex number to use something else than a float to store the real and imaginary parts:

```
template<class Real = float, class Imaginary = Real>
struct complex {
  //...
  Real real;
  Imaginary imaginary;
};
```

- you can use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to handle your array rather than allocating/deallocating yourself, it's a bit safer (you wouldn't have the problem with the copy assignment), but i often directly use dynamic allocation myself so i'm not one to talk
- rather than this:

```
float a, b;
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
  cin>>a>>b;
  numbers[i]=complex(a,b);
}
```

you can overload `operator>>` for `complex` rather than using the assignment operator:

```
std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& output, complex& number) {
  float a, b;
  output >> a >> b;
  number = complex(a, b);
  return output;
}
// ...
int main(int, char*[]) {
  // ...
  for(int i = 0; i < length ; ++i )
    cin >> numbers[i];
  // ...
}
```

(you can also declare the `operator>>` as a friend in complex so that it can directly access its members; when the assignment isn't trivial, it may also slightly improve performance, but not here)
- of course you could define arithmetic operations on complex numbers

...and probably other changes, but that's a rather long list already (and that also depends on what you expect from your classes).

Edit:
Ah something important if you manually handle memory in your class, you may want to define the [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and the [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operator), that may improve performance in some cases:

Let's say you have some function which doubles each complex number in an array and returns a new array (it doesn't modify the original one), let's say its protoype is `Array doubleEachComplex(Array&);`
If you use it like this:

```
Array array;
// ...
array = doubleEachComplex(array);
```

The compiler will:
- construct array
- do things with array (initialize it for instance)
- call doubleEachComplex
- create a fresh `Array` object
- call the copy assignment operator of `Array` (if no move assignment operator is defined)
- delete the fresh `Array` object (used by the copy)

But the copy assignment operator can't modify the "source" object, so it will usually perform a deep copy. A better solution would be to swap the contents of each array since the second one is a temporary (that's what a move constructor could do).
Actually, in that case an even better solution would have been to modify it in place, but that's not always possible/a good idea.